# Why does my SQL code tell me that paddling is not a good identifier?

Tags: oracle

I AM ON CLOUD VERSION OF ORACLE
so what I need to do is insert data from an already established table into a new table. I am a student and I pretty much copied what they told me to do, just changing the table and what i need to grab
here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO PADDLING
SELECT TRIP_ID, TRIP_NAME, STATE, DISTANCE, 
MAX_GRP_SIZE, 
SEASON
FROM TRIP
WHERE TYPE = Paddling;
```

and here is the error

```
ORA-00904: "PADDLING": invalid identifier
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", 
    line 670
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", 
    line 656
    ORA-06512: at 
    "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1768


    4. WHERE TYPE = Paddling;
```

I tried PADDLING in all uppercase, however it is lowercase in the table i am grabbing from.

Comment: You probably mean "Paddling" in the `where` condition to be a string, not a column name. If so, you are missing the single-quotes around the string. Also, if it is lower-case in the table, you will not get a match, because `'paddling'` (lower case) and `'Paddling'` (capitalized initial) are **not** equal!

Comment: As to your specific question, "why does Oracle say Paddling is not a good identifier" - since you gave it without quotes, the parser doesn't know you meant a **value** at that point. A word like Paddling, not enclosed in single quotes, must be a column name, or perhaps a function name (or synonym for a function), etc. - in any case, an object name, also known as "identifier". Your table doesn't have a column named Paddling, and you don't have a function by that name, etc. - so the "identifier" is "invalid". Of course, you didn't **mean** to have an identifier there, you meant a value...

Answer (score 0):

You want to quote the string literal :

```sql
INSERT INTO PADDLING
SELECT TRIP_ID, TRIP_NAME, STATE, DISTANCE, 
MAX_GRP_SIZE, 
SEASON
FROM TRIP
WHERE TYPE = 'Paddling';
```

If you do not have the quotes then Oracle assumes it is an identifier, typically for a column name. To show that it is a string literal and not an identifier you need to use single quotation marks.

Comment: Thank You so much!